# I want to add "-hvr" in the end of img "src" attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Q. I want to add "-hvr" in the end of img "src" attribute when I focus on input type text and remove "-hvr" when field is out of focus. Below is the jQuery code I am using but its not working:

```js
$('.signup-fld > input').click(function() {
  var imgAttr = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '-hvr.jpg');
  $(this).attr("src", imgAttr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="signup-fld">
  <img src="img/user-form-ico.jpg" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" />
</div>
<div class="signup-fld">
  <img src="img/pass-form-ico.jpg" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the change the `src` when a user focus the input and change it again when he leaves, Use `focus` and `focusout`

Hope it helps you

```js
$('.signup-fld > input').focus(function() {
  var img = $(this).prev("img");
  var imgAttr = $(img).attr("src").replace(/\.jpg/, '-hvr.jpg');
  $(img).attr("src", imgAttr)
  console.log($(img).attr("src"))
}).focusout(function() {
  var img = $(this).prev("img");
  var imgAttr = $(img).attr("src").replace(/\-hvr.jpg/, '.jpg');
  $(img).attr("src", imgAttr)
  console.log($(img).attr("src"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="signup-fld"> <img src="img/user-form-ico.jpg" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" />
</div>
<div class="signup-fld"> <img src="img/pass-form-ico.jpg" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `src` from the image, but trying to set it on the input

You can use `attr(function)` to simplify this also

```
$('.signup-fld > input').on('focus blur', function(event) {

  $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src', function(_, existingSrc) {
    if(event.type === 'focus'){
       return existingSrc.replace(/\.jpg/, '-hvr.jpg');
    }else{
       return existingSrc.replace('-hvr', ''); 
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful.